# create folder by that value and how to save file to that folder LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

in my view there is dropdown menu. please how to create folder by that value and how to save file to that folder.

```
            $fileName = now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
                 $destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$fileName;
                 $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath,file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
```

i tried this and it worked. but dont know how to by value

```
 config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.('division').'/'.$fileName;
```

this is it my view

```
<select class="form-control" required="required" name="division">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you first get the destination value:

$division = $request->input('division');

can't you just do this? $destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/' . $division .
 '/' . $fileName;

or am I missing something on your issue?

Comment: Thanks sir if was my mistake :( sorry i didnt notice it.